# Unable to generate image from data coming from backend (angular)

Tags: node.js, angular, postgresql, express

From 2-3 days i'm trying to generate image from the data coming from backend.
My express backend consist of fileds (id, image_1, image_2, image_3) where the images are in the bytea format.
I'm able to get buffer array from the backend side but, while showing that to image format in front-end it's not showing image.

```
<div class="testName">
    place tosho image
    <div >
      <img [src]="image_1_url" alt="">
      <!-- <img [src]="bufferToBase64(image)" alt="Banner Image" /> -->
    </div>
  </div>
```

This is .html part of my angular project.

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    // to print only path eg:"/login"

    this.fetchImagesFromServer().subscribe( (data) => {
      this._imagesData = data
      console.log('image 1 data', this._imagesData.data[0].image_1);
      
      this.displayImage(new Uint8Array(this._imagesData.data[0].image_1.data))
    }, error => { 
      console.error('Error in fetching', error);
     })

    console.log('image_1', this.image_1_url);
    
  }

  fetchImagesFromServer(): Observable<any> {
    const url = 'http://localhost:3000/src/vista-v1/admin/image';
 
    const params = new HttpParams()
      .set('id', 'ea8bebdc-34d3-41b7-9bba-77fbd51ec3ef')
      .set('category', 'Facility');
 
    return this.http.get<any>(url, { params });
  }


  displayImage(imageData: ArrayBuffer): void {
    if (imageData) {
      const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(imageData)
      const imageUrl = this.bufferToUrl(uint8Array);
      this.image_1_url = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(imageUrl);
      // this.image_1_url = imageUrl;

      console.log('Image url 1', this.image_1_url);
      
    }
  }

  bufferToUrl(image: Uint8Array): any {
    if (image) {
      const blob = new Blob([image], { type: 'image/jpeg'})
      const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      return imageUrl
    }

    return ''
  }

  bufferToBase64(image: ArrayBuffer): any {
    let binary = ''
    const bytes  = new Uint8Array(image)
    for(let i = 0; i < bytes.byteLength; i++) {
      binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i])
    }

    console.log('BINATRY DATA IS THIS', binary);
    return'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + btoa(binary)
    
  }
```

this the .component.ts part of my code. Can anyone have idea what will be the issue in this or what I need to make change to generate image?

Comment: can you include backend code sending the file, output of `console.log('image 1 data', this._imagesData.data[0].image_1);` would be good also

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm able to get the cause. It's due to back-end.